# A life depends on B => A and B in same aggregate?

Tags: domain-driven-design

Following DDD methodology, when I have two entities `A` and `B` where `B`'s lifecycle depends on `A`'s lifecyle (I mean that `B` exists only if `A` exists - for example `A` represents an `Application` and `B` represents a running `Instance` of an `Application`), should I deduce that `A` and `B` belong to the same aggregate where `A` is the root?

I've read in many articles and books, and they always say that inside an aggregate, there is a root Entity and other elements. These other elements may be other Entities or Value objects. The identities of the internal Entities are local to the aggregate, so they have a meaning only inside the aggregate. Should I interpret from this last sentence (i.e. local identity) that the lifecycle of the internal Entities depends on the one of the root Entity?

I've already examples on `Stackoverflow`, where two Entities `A` and `B`, with `B`'s lifecycle depending on `A`'s lifecycle (i.e. `B` exists only if `A` exists), are in different aggregates. And generally, it was because the person that asked the question was interested to have two repositories (one for `A` and another for `B`), while following DDD, repositories should be created only for root aggregates.

Thanks to clarify this point

Answer (score 2):

The central function of the aggregate is to create a consistency boundary around a cluster or related entities. This consistency boundary depends on the use case at hand and can even change within a single user case due to technical requirements, such as performance, etc.

> should I deduce that A and B belong to the same aggregate where A is
>   the root?

That can be the case, however you can also have an case where both `Application` and `Instance` are aggregates and `Instance` references `Application` by ID. One this to consider is the notion of eventual consistency. For example, is it OK to delete an application instance such that corresponding application instances are deleted in an eventually consistent manner?

> Should I interpret from this last sentence (i.e. local identity) that
>   the lifecycle of the internal Entities depends on the one of the root
>   Entity?

Yes. Aggregates should encapsulate its constituent entities. External references can only be made to other aggregates either by ID or direct reference, though the recommended approach is to reference by ID.

Check out [Effective Aggregate Design by Vaughn Vernon](http://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011)

Comment: i am actually coming from that series of articles looking for some examples on transactional aggregate consistency. The three articles are awesome. Vaughn made good points but i still have some doubts thou.